# Ввод с клавиатуры не приостанавливая работу программы на python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Как во время работы в терминале программы на python организовать обработку ввода с клавиатуры в фоновом режиме, не приостанавливая при этом работу самой программы? Например у нас есть цикл который должен каждую секунду печатать символ, а в случае если пользователь нажмет клавишу "стрелка вверх" вывести не слеующий символ, а предыдущий. (ОС Linux, python3.5)

```
import time

for x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'l']:
    print(x);
    time.sleep(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Для создания переносимых интерактивных консольных программ, [можно `prompt_toolkit` модуль использовать](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit). Чтобы печатать символы, меняя направление с помощью стрелок:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import string
from collections import deque

from prompt_toolkit import prompt_async  # $ pip install prompt_toolkit
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import Keys, Registry

BACKWARDS, STOP, FORWARD = 1, 0, -1


async def interactive_prompt(direction):
    registry = Registry()

    @registry.add_binding('q')
    @registry.add_binding(Keys.ControlC)
    def stop(event):
        direction[0] = STOP
        event.cli.set_return_value(False)  # exit

    @registry.add_binding(Keys.Up)
    def backwards(event):
        direction[0] = BACKWARDS

    @registry.add_binding(Keys.Down)
    def forward(event):
        direction[0] = FORWARD

    await prompt_async('Press Up/Down/Ctrl-C/q> ',
                       patch_stdout=True,  # show prompt
                       key_bindings_registry=registry)


async def print_chars(direction, chars=deque(string.ascii_lowercase)):
    while direction[0]:
        print(chars[0])
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        chars.rotate(direction[0])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
direction = [FORWARD]
loop.create_task(interactive_prompt(direction))
loop.run_until_complete(print_chars(direction))
```

[image: print-chars-direcitons tty session]

Answer (score 2):

Для сравнения, в качестве альтернативы [asyncio версии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790270/23044), вариант с потоками:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string
import threading
import time
from collections import deque

from prompt_toolkit import prompt  # $ pip install prompt_toolkit
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import Keys, Registry

BACKWARDS, STOP, FORWARD = 1, 0, -1


def interactive_prompt(direction):
    registry = Registry()

    @registry.add_binding('q')
    @registry.add_binding(Keys.ControlC)
    def stop(event):
        direction[0] = STOP
        event.cli.set_return_value(False)  # exit

    @registry.add_binding(Keys.Up)
    def backwards(event):
        direction[0] = BACKWARDS

    @registry.add_binding(Keys.Down)
    def forward(event):
        direction[0] = FORWARD

    prompt('Press Up/Down/Ctrl-C/q> ',
           patch_stdout=True,  # show prompt
           key_bindings_registry=registry)


def print_chars(direction, chars=deque(string.ascii_lowercase)):
    while direction[0]:
        print(chars[0])
        time.sleep(1)
        chars.rotate(direction[0])

direction = [FORWARD]
threading.Thread(target=print_chars, args=[direction], daemon=True).start()
interactive_prompt(direction)
```

Внешнее поведение совпадает c [asyncio примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790270/23044).