# Выход из бесконечного цикла while True по вводу значения с клавиатуры

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, multiprocessing

Добрый день, что то никак не могу нагуглить, помогите пожалуйста. Осваиваю Python 3, стоит задача в бесконечном цикле:

```
while a=1:
    print('Something')
```

который можно прервать вводом значения a:

```
a = input('Enter a')
```

Как это правильно сделать? В голову пришло разделить это с помощью multiprocessing на два отдельных потока , но на функции с a=input() код выпадает в ошибку. Или я не туда пошел?
Спасибо

UPD. для понятности выкладываю упрощенный код.

```
...
class AB:
    def __call__(self):
        while a = 1:
            print('Hello')

class CD:
    def __call__(self):
        a = input('Enter a=')

if __name__ == __main__:
    a = AB()
    b = CD()
    p1 = Process(target = a)
    p2 = Process(target = b)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Этот код потоки запускает, цикл работает а на input() ошибка:

```
input('Enter a=')
EOFError:EOF when reading line
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? В операторе break или в неблокирующем чтении нажатой клавиши?

Comment: Если я верно понял ваш вопрос - то второе...

Comment: если интересно, то о EOFError в дочернем процессе, отдельный вопрос задайте. Связанный вопрос [Is there any way to pass 'stdin' as an argument to another process in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8976962/4279)

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы прервать Питон-скрипт, запущенный в консоли, не нужно дочерние процессы запускать, достаточно <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> нажать:

```
while True:
    print('Something')
```

Если вы не хотите на traceback с `KeyboardInterrupt` исключением смотреть, можно свой обработчик сигнала установить перед запуском цикла:

```
import os
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda *_: os._exit(1))  # exit on Ctrl+C
```

или обернуть в try/except KeyboardInterrupt код в основном потоке.

Чтобы произвольный ввод принимать пока цикл выполняется, можно его в отдельном потоке запустить:

```
import threading

def loop():
    while True:
        print('something')

threading.Thread(target=loop, daemon=True).start()
input('Press <Enter> to exit.')
```

В этом случае, выход происходит по нажатию на <kbd><Enter></kbd>, так как поток объявлен как **`daemon=True`**, поэтому он не переживёт основной поток (в котором мы ввод ожидали). Если убрать `daemon=True`, то *дочерний поток продолжил бы выполняться и по прекращению основного потока.*

Если вы не хотите из программы выходить по окончанию цикла, то можно явное событие использовать, чтобы прервать цикл:

```
import threading


def loop(done, interval=1):
    while not done.wait(interval):
        print('something')


done = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=loop, args=[done], daemon=True).start()
input('Press Enter to exit.')
done.set()  # break the loop
```

Если пауза между итерациями вам не нужна, то просто `while not done.is_set():` условие можно использовать для цикла.

Более общий случай: [Ввод с клавиатуры не приостанавливая работу программы на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790239/23044).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0
while a < 1:
    print('Something')
    a = input('quit:')
    if a == 'quit':
        break
```

Это не вариант?

Comment: ну тогда же цикл остановиться и будет ждать input... Нужно что бы он все время крутился, пока не понадобится его срочно остановить.

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep
import threading


def main():
    while pause.wait():
        sleep(1)
        print('Hello')


def off():
    while True:
        if keyboard.wait('Ctrl + 1') is None: # активация цикла на Ctrl + 1
            pause.set()
        if keyboard.wait('Ctrl + 2') is None: # остановка цикла на Ctrl + 2
            pause.clear()


pause = threading.Event()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=main)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=off)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

ставит на паузу, не завершая программу,
мб кому-то пригодится